# CDI: Injecting a bean produced by a dependency

Tags: java, maven, cdi, quarkus

I'm creating a maven dependency, which has a `MessageHandler` class.
Alongside which there is a MessageHandlerProduceer class:

```
public class MessageHandlerProducer {

    @Produces
    public MessageHandler messageHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler();
    }
}
```

Having listed the dependency in the core project, and when I'm trying to inject the `MessageHandler` bean, I'm getting the following error:

```
Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.example.MessageHandler and qualifiers [@Default]
```

Comment: Is this a multi-module maven project? If so: do you use [Jandex](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#how-to-generate-a-jandex-index) in the sub-module that provieds above producer-method?

Comment: Yes, it's a multi-module project, and that solved it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a multi-module setup, we need information of beans provided by sibling modules. The easiest way to generate those information is [enabling Jandex support through the `jandex-plugin`](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#how-to-generate-a-jandex-index).

For Maven, the following snippet should be added to the module providing the producer:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
      <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-index</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jandex</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

For gradle, the following snippet can be used:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.kordamp.gradle.jandex' version '0.11.0'
}
```

Both snippets are taken from the documentation linked above and are only included to make this answer self-contained. Credits for those go to [Red Hat](https://www.redhat.com/en), as they are the maintainer of quarkus and provide the snippets in the documentation linked above.